# MySql when Insert Duplicate, Replace or Ignore under certain conditions

Tags: mysql

I want to create a MySql query to insert into a table and when duplication happens, I want to check the existing record to determine whether to REPLACE or IGNORE. When a certain field of the existing record is 0 then do REPLACE, otherwise do IGNORE. How can this be done in a performant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your "check" column (the one that should be 0 for an update to happen) is c2, you could do something like that:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, c2, c3, c4)
VALUES
    (1, 'val2', 'val3', 'val4')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    c2 = IF(c2 = 0, VALUES(c2), c2),
    c3 = IF(c2 = 0, VALUES(c3), c3),
    c4 = IF(c2 = 0, VALUES(c4), c4);
```

It's basically an `INSERT ... IGNORE` if `c2 != 0`, and otherwise an `INSERT ... UPDATE`, which I think is what you want.

Of course you can adapt it to your needs, no need to update all the colums, or use the same check for each column

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique composite index on number and name.

```
Alter table table1 Add unique index idx_unq(`number`,`name`);
```

Then do an Insert `Ignore INTO table1(number,name) VALUES(num, name);`

That should prevent duplicate from being inserted into the table.

useful link for http://www.sitepoint.com/use-unique-indexes-mysql-databases/

Comment: Thanks Krishna but I want to keep only one row for duplicated rows. So have to do either REPLACE or IGNORE.

Comment: hi @brewphone, table1(number,name)  VALUES(num, name);

 which are replace or ignore, remaining are duplicated

Comment: Understood Krishna and your solution works. Just don't want to alter my table so I chose the other answer. Thanks